# WiX - Creating MSI and MSP for patching

Tags: wix, windows-installer, msp

I have created a configuration tool which uses WiX to create MSI and with reference to previous MSI can build MSP.

This configuration tool will be used by even customer to create their MSI and MSP.

I will deliver the installer to customer (MSI or MSP)
Here I want to make sure that when customer are using it all GUIDs ProductCode, UpgradeCode, Component ID needed to be same...

One way of maintaining is storing all GUIDs in a XML file and store it as binary in installer and when customer creating their MSI or MSP they refer to the binary file in the MSI or MSP that I have provided.

I want you see is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to also store .wixpdb and msi file in your archive because for MSP Wix need wixpdb for reference and creating the patch. Refering the original configuration and files only possible if you keep a copy of .wixpdb and msi.

How to create MSP is there in wix tutorial...

Comment: Where is "there"?

Comment: presumably this: https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/patchwork/